# How to map a table into two entities, but with a common LastUpdatedTime/Concurrency check

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am coding to an existing database schema, dictated by a legacy app.  Many tables have large numbers of columns.  I have successfully used the table-split pattern so that, for example, I have:

```
public class Product {

   public int ProductId {get; set;}

   // Primary fields from Products table

   public ProductExtra ExtraDetails {get; set;}

}

public class ProductExtra {

   public int ProductId {get; set;}

   // Secondary fields from Products table

}
```

The Products table has a LastUpdated timestamp field, used both for audit and concurrency.  It is not database managed  - it needs to be set by code.   I need to ensure that if I update either Product or ProductExtra that this is updated, and that if I were to update fields in both objects in the same transaction, that I would not fall foul of concurrency problems. Code first won't let me have a LastUpdated property in both objects mapping to the same column.

I tried adding a reference from ProductExtra back to Product and then trying to update LastUpdated on Product when I saved changes to ProductExtra.  This mapped OK, but I just got a data update error saying that there was a circular dependency that couldn't be resolved.